# how to get and read an xml file in a zip file using xml.etree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, zip

I need to get the xml file tree from a zip file using the xml library.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('knifk.catrobat') as z:
    with z.ElementTree.parse("code.xml") as code:
        pass
```

**WARNING**: the "catrobat" file type opens as zip

I can't use the construction "with z.open("code.xml ", "r") as f:" because python gives an error: AttributeError: 'ZipFile' object has no attribute 'ElementTree'

when I use "tree = ElementTree.parse("code.xml ")" python does not find this file

Comment: `z` is the opened zipfile, you need to read the contained XML before passing it to element tree. Check out [ZipFile.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import zipfile

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with zipfile.ZipFile("knifk.catrobat.", mode="r") as archive:
        tree = ElementTree.fromstring(archive.read("code.xml"))
```

The `tree` variable is of type `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`.